# Springboot application does not find JPA repositories when run from command line jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot application that runs fine  (using JPA) from IntelliJ and also using gradlew bootRun from the command line.
Howwever, when I generate jars for the application using bootJar and run the application using java -cp  I see that Spring does not find the JPA repositories :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = [ "com.myapp.workspace"] )
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan( "com.myapp.workspace.config" )
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Settings::class, Git::class, RTC::class)
public class MyMain(
       @Autowired
        private val projectAreaRepository: ProjectAreaRepository,
```

The projectAreaRespository is in com.myapp.workspace.repository. The command line I am using is:

```
java -cp c:\jars\* com.myapp.workspace.MyMain
```

This code runs perfectly fine when I do a gradlew bootRun from the command line. Also from inside IntelliJ. So I assume all my annotations are correct.

The log shows :

```
2023-11-27T17:20:09.145+05:30 DEBUG 26900 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@30ea8c23
2023-11-27T17:20:09.689+05:30  INFO 26900 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-11-27T17:20:09.705+05:30  INFO 26900 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
```

And further down :

```
Parameter 2 of constructor in com.myapp.workspace.MyMain required a bean of type 'com.myapp.workspace.repository.ProjectAreaRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


    Action:
    
    Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myapp.workspace.repository.ProjectAreaRepository' in your configuration.
    
    2023-11-27T17:20:11.503+05:30 ERROR 26900 --- [           main] c.i.r.workspace.MyMain$Companion  : Error creating bean with name 'myMain': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.workspace.repository.ProjectAreaRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myMain': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.workspace.repository.ProjectAreaRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
```

Any hints on what could be wrong is highly appreciated.

Following JPA entries are in the application.yaml and the yaml is as well part of the jar :

The JPA entries are here :

```
  datasource:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        url: jdbc:h2:./DataSpring/rtc.workspace.h2;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
        username: sa
        password: sa
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
        open-in-view: false
        show-sql: false
        properties:
            hibernate:
                enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
            path:    /h2-console
            settings:
                trace: true
                web-allow-others: true
```

Comment: are there any jpa related entries in application.properties file? Is it packaged into the jar? Adjust class path settings if running from cmdline to include the properties file

Comment: Yes, the application.yaml is packaged in the jar. The JPA entries are here :

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? Can you reproduce the issue using a new project from Spring Initializr? Does changing `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan( "com.myapp.workspace.config" )` to `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan( "com.myapp.workspace" )` change anything?

Comment: Spring boot v 3.1.2 . Using @ConfigurationPropertiesScan( "com.myapp.workspace" ) does not change anything. Apparently it is something to do with the way the jar got generated or the dependencies associated with it since the code runs fine when i do a gradlew bootRun

Comment: Almost assured that something is getting omitted from your jar. I would inspect your  jar to make sure everything you expect is there. There's not enough information here to answer your question. Would need to see how you're building your jar. When you run in IntelliJ by the way, you can see the launch parameters in the first line. It's truncated by default.

Comment: Resolved the issue by using the plain jar generated by the gradle build and pointing to dependencies jar folder in the classpath, instead of using the fat jar generated by gradle bootJar. Thanks for the inputs.